# Java File Upload using socket,Percentage of uploded file required?

Tags: java, android, sockets

Hii i am uploading a file to server using socket and i need the percent of file loaded?how can i do that?i have the maximun value i.e the file length ,how can i get how much file has been uploaded?

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fil);
                BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(skt.getOutputStream());

                //Write the file to the server socket           
                int i;

                while ((i = in.read()) != -1) {
                    publishProgress(???);
                    out.write(i);                   
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
```

I need to pass the length of file uploded in the publishProgress method.

Comment: Read up on Listener-Observer patterns. PublishProgress in this case probably would spit out to a bunch of Listeners all of whom are subscribed. At that point you have your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using buffered copying

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fil);
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(skt.getOutputStream());

//Write the file to the server socket
int i;
int written = 0;
byte[] buf = new byte[512];

while ((i = in.read(buff)) != -1) {  

    out.write(buff,0,i);
    written += i;
    publishProgress((double)written/length);
    //passing a double value from 0-1 to say how much is transmitted (length is length of file)
    System.out.println(buff+", "+i);
}
```

Comment: hey by using your in.read(buff) my uploading speed increased..thks a lot..and can you plz explain the increase in speed reason?

Comment: because byte by byte transfer means that you have to go through the loop n times (n being the size of the file) which has to check for each byte whether it the end, whether to outputstream has to flush and printing the value. But using a buffer like I showed means that chunks of up to 512 bytes are passed through the loop and the aforementioned overhead is don't only once prr chunk

Answer (score 0):

Below is your modified code. *written* holds the number of ints written to the socket.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fil);
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(skt.getOutputStream());

//Write the file to the server socket           
int i;
int written = 0;

while ((i = in.read()) != -1) {  

    out.write(i);               
    publishProgress(++written);
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to do one of a couple of things:

1. Use a Flash uploader such as `swfupload` (see http://demo.swfupload.org/Documentation/) as these typically provide access to upload progress of this sort.
2. Provide a back channel of your own: perform the form submit with Ajax and then while the form submit occurs you run a javascript timer that hits a URL on the server with a key of some kind that corresponds to the upload. The URL on the server looks up how much of the file has been uploaded and returns that number and you pass that through to your `uploadProgress` method.

Answer (score 0):

javax.swing.ProgressMonitorInputStream